# wrong timezone with clock and jackson

Tags: java, datetime, jackson

I'm using jackson to de-/serialize dtos. I made some custom configuration for jacksons `ObjectMapper` and `Clock` as the following code shows:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper()
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
    mapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat);

    return mapper;
}

@Bean
@Profile("!testing")
public Clock clock()
{
    return Clock.systemDefaultZone();
}
```

For testing I defined my custom clock (SettableClock):

```
@Bean
@Profile("testing")
public Clock clock()
{
    return new SettableClock(); // extends Clock
}
```

In my database I store some dates in the following format: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

When I create a new database entry I get the following result:
`1 | 2016-10-16 18:42:55` (german time, UTC+2) which is correct.

This Date will be created from an Instant, using the defined clock:

```
Instant now = Instant.now(clock);
return new Timestamp(now.toEpochMilli());
```

My problem is now that jackson converts the date in a wrong way and not as defined in the object mapper configuration. Eg. `2016-10-16T16:42:55Z` which is not UTC+2..

I discovered this problem when writing a test, because in my test when I create a new Instant using Instant.now() I'm getting the time from UTC+2 (local time). Same result when using new Date() in js for example.

As I understand the jackson documentation my object mapper configuration seems valid. But why jackson doesn't make use of it? In debug mode I can see that my configuration will applied.

This code shows how I include the configured object mapper:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters)
    {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        jacksonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        converters.add(jacksonConverter);

        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why I'm still getting a wrong time zone? 
When serializing a date using +02:00 everything works as expected. Just the deserialization doesn't work :(

I also tried to configure the clock especially to create times in UTC+2 but this doesn't change anything. The problem seems to be located in my object mapper I guess...

Regards, Tim

Comment: Instant is time zone neutral (essentially always in UTC), which could be part of the problem.  Using Instant also implies you're logging something (historical data), which should be stored in UTC.  The original date-time formatting classes aren't threadsafe, you need a new one for each thread.  Is it possible to use java.time classes all the way down?  Next, whenever you store a date-time value, you also need to store the time zone, or ambiguity could hurt you later.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Regarding the database date: I'm using postgresql with `TIMESTAMPTZ` (with time zone), so I'm always getting the date with the corresponding time zone. Using java.time everywhere would be great but even when I append ` mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);` to my object mapper configuration Instant will be serialized as timestamp, what is definitely not what I want. Imho Writing a customer serializer for Instants is not the right way, because jackson already provides this options out of the box but for java.util.Date ..

Comment: try adding @EnableWebMvc

Comment: @danidacar doesn't change anything :( . As I'm using spring boot EnableWebMvc isn't mandatory at all, right?

Comment: try using WebMvcConfigurationSupport like here https://dzone.com/articles/customizing

Comment: As mentioned there customizing with WebMvcConfigurationSupport should only be necessary in spring mvc projects. But I tried it out and it got executed but produces timestamps for java.util.Date as well. I also tried to register the jackson converter as bean but nothing changed :(